# Can you suppress error reporting of SVG error on browser console?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M 123.2,{desc} l -6,6 l …".
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M 115.2,{desc} h -28.8 l…".
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M 115.2,{desc} l -6,6 l …".
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M 123.2,{desc} h -36.8 l…".
```

I used Javascript to feed variable values to the placeholders later, so I wonder can I disable these errors.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [data- attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) as the placeholder and when you get the data populate the d from the values and the data attribute together. That way the d attribute is never invalid.